# Accentuated characters inside an UTF-8 encoded xml document

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8

In an xml document with following header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

I have following segment:

```
<FDT>a-Vérification selon CT 62-20-00-604
b-Controle(s)*/** à effectuer
c-Outillage(s)utilisé(s) soumis à contrôle
d-Application SB/NT/CN
e-Vérification des points vitaux
f-Contrôle outillage (MO DGA EV  354 048 S-CAT)
g-Traçabilité des fluides et ingrédients soumis à péremption utilisés(MO DGA EV 354-062 S-CAT)
</FDT>
```

Is it okay to find some accentuated characters ("é", "à" or "ç") inside an UTF-8 encoded document and not "Ã©", "Ã¨" or "Ã§"?

I'm also wondering if there are some issues with carriage return?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared UTF-8 and if the accentuated characters are UTF-8 every thing is fine.

Carriage return has nothing to do with the encoding.

Comment: Yes @jhinghaus, this is what my question is about. I'm not sure accentuated characters are allowed in UTF-8 (I wouldn't say no). And I'm not sure the response is this simple.

Comment: Do not worry, accentuated characters are allowed. UTF-8 covers almost all of the characters and symbols in the world.